# Copy huge data from Netezza to Teradata

Tags: netezza

We are planning to Copy huge data (250 Billion Rows/5 TB) from Netezza to Teradata. What is the best way to copy this data?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use an External Table to build the flatfile in Netezza.

Then use Teradata MultiLoad or Teradata FastLoad to load the file.

Answer (score 0):

[Sneakernet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sneakernet).  Seriously.  Download the data to microSDs, USB keys, DVDs, whatever.  Ship it & reload.  It'll be faster than transferring across the Internet.

There's an old quote "[Never underestimate the bandwidth of a station wagon full of 9 track tapes](http://www.dansdata.com/gz105.htm)".  There's an update [that computes the bandwidth of a single Boeing 747 full of Blu-Ray disks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sneakernet).
It's impressive.

Comment: Thanks Dan for the update. We will try this option but data sensitivity issue. Are we having any other option to copy the data from NZ to TD.

Answer (score 0):

You could script it using Python or Perl and run load in parallel.
Speed will be limited only by your network bandwidth and Teradata insert.

Answer (score 0):

From Netezza to Teradata:
1) Export data off of Netezza:
Connect to Netezza using nzodbcsql, it is faster than nzsql.

Invoke NZODBC
nzodbcsql -host nzservername -port 5480 -d NZDATABASE -u user -pw password -f /NZ_EXPORT_LOACATION/NZ_EXPORT_SCRIPT

(-f is the NZ_EXPORT_SCRIPT you will call)

The script should look something like this:
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE '/NZ_EXPORT_DIR/DATAFILE.csv' USING  (remotesource 'ODBC' DELIMITER ',' NullValue '' escapechar '\' ctrlchars 'yes' crinstring 'yes') AS SELECT * FROM NZDATABASE.TABLE;

If you have a large fact table you can chunk it up by using "where ((1 <= datasliceid) AND  (datasliceid <= 31));"  put this after your select in the script you'll want to go up to 92 dataslices, or however many you have on your box.

2) Fastload the data into Teradata.

---

I intially answered the wrong question: but for what it is worth this is how you copy huge data from Teradata to Greenplum:

Fast Export the data from Teradata, you will probably need to run SED on the data that was Fast Exported to remove some of the garbage characteres.  SCP/FTP the data over to a GreenPlum ETL head node (GZIP --fast) if you want a smaller file.  Create your YAML and GPLoad the data.  Start with a small set of data first.

If you want to go from Netezza to Greenplum use the same NZODBC Export to a flat file, then use GPLOAD to load the flat file for the NZODBC Exported flat file.